# Sugestão do ESLint no import do React

Tags: react-native, eslint

Na linha `import React, { Component } from 'react';` o ESLint marca o import e traz a seguinte mensagem:

```
[eslint] Definition for rule 'react/require-extension' was not found (react/require-extension)
```

O sistema funciona tudo ok, e todas as outras mensagens consegui arrumar, porém está não estou achando jeito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso quer dizer que tens uma regra personalizada que o ESLint não encontra. Essa regra foi [descontinuada na versão 7](http://annickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/162b92b9015070164cede91a7d8fedc140f45885/CHANGELOG.md#breaking).
E lá diz assim:

> Remove deprecated require-extension rule, use the eslint-plugin-import extensions rule instead

Ou seja, troca e usa [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import).